# Laravel Livewire Bad Performance on Simple Operation

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire component that's displaying a list of tasks on a page, and when the user clicks one of the tasks, it emits the edit event and opens a modal to display the data related to that specific task.

It's a pretty simple component, and I'm unclear on why it would be performing so poorly, but it takes forever for the modal to display.

Here's the relevant parts of my component:

```
protected $listeners = ['edit', 'goToNextStatus'];

public function mount()
{
    $this->loadTasks();
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.tasks.work-list');
}

public function edit($id)
{
     //I can DD anywhere in this method and it will return a result super fast.
    $this->task = Task::find($id);
    $this->taskStatusId = $this->task->task_status_id;
    $this->taskAssignee = $this->task->assigned_to;
    $this->description = $this->task->description;
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('showModal', 'editTask');
}
```

The fact that I can dd anywhere in the `edit` method and get a very fast response tells me that it's something that's happening *after* the the edit method.

Originally I had the `loadTasks` method called in the render method, and I moved that to the mount method to try and eliminate that from the mix. It still runs the same, and I'm fairly confident the mount method is only run once on page load, so that shouldn't be a factor.

I know that other lifecycle hooks are called after my method, but I'm not tapping into any of those. How can I figure out where the bottleneck is?

I installed debug bar and I'm seeing 1940 duplicated queries. Each of them are running for a very short amount of time, so I can't imagine they're causing any bottleneck, but it does seem like a lot of queries.

I watched [this video](https://youtu.be/MbksBczShcA) and started looking at the models that were loaded. There were 2499 models loaded. I was able to trim that down to ~500 on initial page load which is much improved.

The problem I'm still seeing and I'm very confused by is when I click the row in the table to open up the edit modal, it's taking FOREVER, and it's running queries that I can't determine where they're coming from:

[image]

Nowhere am I calling that query with the whereIn on the tasks table. I don't understand. I've emptied out the modal so all it is is the shell, so there's nothing happening in a loop or anything like that.

Literally the only code being called that I can see is the `edit` method I've shown above. The `Task` model isn't using `$with` to load any relationships automatically. It is using `$withCount`, but even if I comment that out it's not having any effect.

Comment: Try to debug with XDebug, in this case you can inspect the whole application lifecycle

Comment: I couldn't get xdebug working, so I ended up installing debugbar which is helpful.

Comment: Maybe you could opt in using wire:init to load the tasks instead of the mount() function because mount is blocking, and display a loading indicator first, does this open the modal faster?